# Do function not have access to window object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, local-storage, javascript-objects

why does this code work:
'''`<button type="button" id="clear" onclick="window.localStorage.clear();">delete accounts</button>`'''
but this does not:
'''

```
document.getElementsById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.localStorage.clear()
});
```

'''

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message? Have you tried to use the debugger?

Comment: how do you inject the script to the html? most probably the script is loaded before the html is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `getElementsById` method since id should be unique. Therefore you should use `getElementById` instead:

```js
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(window)
      window.localStorage.clear()
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="clear">delete accounts</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe I missed that typo. :)

Comment: Glad I could help.